# How to make $(this) accessible from inside a function-parameter of a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a jQuery plugin and I need to have a handler for `accept` event, so I created one in the `opts` object of my plugin. The plugin can be called like below:

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
  $("#dialog2").dialog("show", {
    modal: false,
    width: "500px",
    onAccept: function() {
      alert("Homepage changed.");
      $("#dialog2").dialog("close"); // this one works
      $(this).dialog("close"); // this one doesn't. $(this) is undefined...
      // $(this) should be $("#dialog2") in this case.
    }
  });
});
```

Inside the plugin, there is something to call this function:

```
$.fn.dialog = function(command, options) {
  var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.dialog.defaults, options);
  $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 27 && opts.acceptEscape) { commandClose() }
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && opts.acceptEnter) {
      if(opts.onAccept != null) { opts.onAccept(); }
    }
  });
}
```

How should I call this function for **`$(this)`** to work inside it?

For a better understanding of my problem, the entire plugin can be found **[here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8453235/)**.

Comment: where is the code for the `dialog`?

Comment: You can use [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)/[.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) like

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)/[.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) like

```
//assuming here `this` refers tot the correct element
var self = this;
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which== 27 && opts.acceptEscape) {
        commandClose()
    }
    if (e.which== 13 && opts.acceptEnter) {
        if (opts.onAccept != null) {
            opts.onAccept.call(self);
        }
    }
});
```

Note: Also use [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) which is a normalized value

Comment: @LearningNeverStops since OP said the code is inside the plugin method... we could guess so

Comment: @LearningNeverStops if `this` actually is the `dialog` then the most appropriate way of doing that would be to catch the element by its id, since there wouldn't be any other elements with the same id, and the target of the function would always be the same `dialog`

Comment: @Arun I understand, but the line before `$(this)` in OP's question is `$("#dialog2").dialog("close"); // this one works`, which might give indication that he wants the `dialog2` as `this`

Comment: @Amin, very true, so it should be `opts.onAccept.call($("#dialog2"));` i guess

Comment: @LearningNeverStops since the dialog plugin is initialized using `$("#dialog2").dialog(...)`, `this` inside the plugin will refer to the `#dialog2` element

Comment: I'm saying it should be `$('#dialog2').dialog("close");` not `$(this).dialog("close");` inside the `onAccept`

Comment: @ArunPJohny hmm, still your `var self = this` in line one would mean `window` in browser rt?

Comment: @LearningNeverStops a rough implementation will be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/drh883ts/1/

Comment: Wow, I've been away for 5 minutes and look! In my case, I want `$(this)` to be equal to `$("#dialog2")`. Isn't this ok? Please, tell me if there is a better approach (maybe, the approach of jQuery UI's dialog)

Comment: @Victor can you share the code for the `dialog` plugin.. without it we can only guess

Comment: I was sure about that, because it is the first plugin that I am writing without a tutorial :D. Would you like to continue this discussion on the chat? I would like to learn something good today, if you have the necessary time, of course!

Comment: we can catchup later sometime... like today evening or tomorrow morning... now I won't be able to spent lot more time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62093/discussion-between-victor-and-arun-p-johny).